# How to create HTML5 data-* in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQuery mobile and I need to include data-prefetch attribute in a link created with HTML.ActionLink.   I've found examples on Stackoverflow of how to pass data-* attributes in the standard way with object Html attributes. However I can't seem  figure out how to create an attribute that has no value. Best I can create is data-prefetch="" by using `new{data_prefetch=""}` .  I'm assuming that isn't the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can do it like in empty XHTML-attributes: just use the attributes name as its value, like `data-prefetch="data-prefetch"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see using data-prefetch="data-prefetch" works fine. So I guess there is no need to do anything else.

Thanks feeela